# UITableViewCell missing deletion control after successive left-swipes

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I use a tableview with editable custom style cells. There's an `Edit` button in the navigation bar which toggles editing mode. I need the editing mode to delete and reorder rows.

When I left-swipe a cell, the `Delete` action button shows on the right side of that cell. While it is displayed, I press the `Edit` button and the `Delete` action button disappears. Pressing the `Edit` button again shows the deletion command left and the reordering controls right of ALL(!) cells. So far all as expected.

Now (as an example), when I left-swipe cell 0, then left-swipe cell 1 while `Delete` action button in cell 0 is still visible, activating editing mode with `Edit` button now shows deletion command left and reordering control right of all cells, EXCEPT(!) cell 0.

I found out that as soon as 2 or more cells are left-wiped, the first cell which is not right-swiped back out of editing mode, misses the deletion control (left) when editing mode for all cells is enabled using `Edit` button. Even more weird ... on subject cell missing deletion control (left), the reordering control (right) shows correctly!

I followed and compared many tutorials but didn't catch the error.

What do I miss?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
}

// not necessary = didn't change anything, but found in many tutorials
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}

@IBAction func editAction(_ sender: Any) { // that's the Edit button action
    self.setEditing(!isEditing, animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
}
```

Above all involved methods. Irrelevant method content is omitted to keep the post compact. I will add/edit if deemed required.

[image: screenshot 1]
View after left-swipe of cell 1 (disregard `Rename` and `Share` actions).

[image: screenshot 2]
View after left-swipe of cell 2, then cell 1, then entering editing mode using `Edit` button.

Comment: Can you please post some screenshots with the bug, otherwise it is very hard to imagine what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the misbehaviour. Since I use animation in the `setEditing()` method, I need to to tell the view that there are updates using `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`. That did the job! No badly displayed cells anymore neither simulator, nor device!

```
@IBAction func editAction(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.setEditing(!isEditing, animated: true)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Above (`beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`) works as desired, but below (`performBatchUpdates {}`) is more modern (iOS 11.0) and should be preferred.

```
@IBAction func editAction(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.performBatchUpdates {
        self.setEditing(!isEditing, animated: true)
    }
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Meanwhile I believe that the OP misbehaviour is an iOS bug.

By chance, I found that the Safari Bookmarks tableview behaves the same way. Left-swipe cell 0, then left-swipe cell 1, next press `Done`/`Edit` button (lower right corner) twice. You can observe that cell 0 doesn't show the deletion control icon (one-way-sign) left side of cell 0. Consequently I believe this is a iOS bug.

Besides this, other apps produce the same misbehaviour on editing tableviews.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe your problem can be fixed by using UITableView's preset `editButtonItem`.

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
```

this sets state of the button into *edit* mode when a swipe action is being performed, therefore should fix the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no ... your suggestion doesn't work. This was already part of the repertoire I tried before posting here. I tried it again and can confirm that it doesn't work. Meanwhile ... I'm pretty sure that the misbehaviour starts with the first cell not being right-swiped (= cancelling editing mode for that particular cell). When I do this manually, it works. But when I leave it up to the tableviewcell logic, it doesn't work. Again, when I left-swipe the second cell, the first cell editing mode **optically** disables, but I think that it doesn't **logically** disable.

Comment: Did you remove the editing and setEditing methods? These are not required as they are handed automatically when using the editButtonItem. If not then I recommend trying to use the editButtonItem without the edit methods you are currently using.

Comment: Xcode requires override using ``setEditing()`` method (error if override not used). However I can omit this method completely. All works fine without now, even when not using ``editButtonItem``.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t clarify that properly, I meant removing the whole of both of the methods and then only using the editButtonItem.